# How can I define different files or packages inside the Go playground?

Tags: go, go-playground

How can I define different files or packages inside the [Go playground](https://play.golang.org)?

Specially for checking it can be handy to define a package inside the playground. But to manage this I need to define different files. How can I manage this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The playground supports now different files. To define a file you need to write:

```
-- path/to/file.go --
package myPackage

// ...
-- foo/foo.go --
/*
Package foo defines Bar() for showing how
multiple files can be used inside the playground
*/
package foo

import "fmt"

func Bar() {
    fmt.Println("The Go playground now has support for multiple files!")
}
```

To call your package you need to import that package. Therefore you need to define a Go module inside a separate go.mod file.

```
-- go.mod --
module play.ground
```

Now you can import your package you defined inside the playground:

```
package main

import "play.ground/foo"

func main() {
    foo.Bar()
}
```

Putting everything together: https://play.golang.org/p/KLZR7NlVZNX

Comment: Now if only we could change the tab size.

Comment: Is it possible to access asset files, e.g. HTML templates? The playground would allow me to add them, but I have no idea how to reach them.

Comment: @apxp I'm confused about how this works. I want to access a struct I have defined in another file. Do I need to create a separate go.mod file? I can't find any official docs on this.